# How to prove that a subset is compact or not?

Tags: general-topology

Sorry for my bad english.

I understand the concept of compactness in theory, but I'm unable to apply it in practice...

For example, is this subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ compact or not ?

$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq e^x, x \geq 0, x+y \leq 2 \}$

I don't see how to prove (or not) the compactness of this subset. It's an example, but maybe on one example the definition will seem clearer to me. Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the "closed and bounded" definition of compact sets?

Comment: Hint: In $\mathbb R^2$ $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ is compact iff $A$ is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of those less or equal signs ,you should be able to see that A is a closed set in R^2 . you can also see for (x,y) e A that y>= e^x>0  and x>=0 so from    x+y <=2 we see 0<=x <=x+y<=2 and similarly 0<=y<=2 .this means A is a closed and bounded set in R^2 .By the Bolzano Weiertrass theorem ,closed and bounded sets in R^2 with the Euclidean metric are compact .Stuart M.N